# How to filter by keyword all the people somebody is following on Twitter

Tags: twitter

I'm interested in the people that a person is following. I could see every person of that list manually, but it is a huge list. I'd like to filter the people of that list according to a criteria like some words of their descriptions.

How to do it with Twitter? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

So far, I have not found any webapp able to do that. It is possible to do your own application as rchoi answer me here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/get-all-the-users-somebody-is-following-to-filter-the-ones-that-have-a-text-in-their-description/57143

I have googled how to do it with nodejs (search string: github javascript twitter api). I have found the following one, though it seems there are a lot of similar API clients in different programming languages: https://github.com/ttezel/twit